# Many-to-many SQL selection

Tags: sql, many-to-many

I'm currently writing a tag cloud system.

So I wrote the following sql schema :

```
CREATE TABLE bookmark_model_bookmark (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    link VARCHAR(255), 
    title VARCHAR(140), 
    description TEXT, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE bookmark_model_tag (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    name VARCHAR(20), 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE bookmark_tag (
    bookmark_model_bookmark_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    bookmark_model_tag_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (bookmark_model_bookmark_id, bookmark_model_tag_id), 
    CONSTRAINT bookmark_model_bookmark_tags_fk FOREIGN KEY(bookmark_model_bookmark_id) REFERENCES bookmark_model_bookmark (id), 
    CONSTRAINT bookmark_model_tag_bookmarks_fk FOREIGN KEY(bookmark_model_tag_id) REFERENCES bookmark_model_tag (id)
);
```

And fill it with a small amount of data :

```
SELECT * FROM bookmark_model_bookmark;

1|http://braindead.fr|braindead|
2|http://example.fr|example|example text

SELECT * FROM bookmark_model_tag;

1|test
2|braindead
3|example

SELECT * FROM bookmark_tag;

1|1
1|2
2|1
2|3
```

In more readable terms :

- Bookmark #1 named braindead refer to http://braindead.fr/ and have two tags : "test" and "braindead".
- Bookmark #2 named example refer to http://example.fr/ and have to tags "test" and "example".

So the next step of my development is to select all the tag linked to bookmarks which are tagged with a list of selected tag.

For example is I pass in parameter "test" it must return "braindead" AND "example" because both are tagged with test tag.

But if I pass in parameter "test" and "braindead", only "braindead" must be returned by the query because it's the only bookmark tagged with "test" AND "braindead".

```
SELECT *
FROM bookmark_model_tag AS tag
INNER JOIN bookmark_tag ON (bookmark_tag.bookmark_model_tag_id = tag.id)
WHERE bookmark_tag.bookmark_model_bookmark_id IN ( /* Here my subquery */ );
```

But I can't manage to find out the subquery. I have start with something like this :

```
SELECT bookmark.id
FROM bookmark_model_bookmark AS bookmark
INNER JOIN bookmark_tag ON (bookmark.id = bookmark_tag.bookmark_model_bookmark_id)
WHERE /* what to write here ? */
```

Just to be precise, input parameter of my query is an array of tags id.

So here I'm stuck.

**EDIT**

I'm using an ORM (sqlalchemy) for build my queries, and it's build queries which looks like this :

```
SELECT tag.id AS tag_id, tag.name AS tag_name, count(tag.id) AS count_1 
FROM tag, bookmark_tag, (
  SELECT bookmark.id AS id 
  FROM bookmark, bookmark_tag 
  WHERE bookmark.id = bookmark_tag.bookmark_id 
  AND bookmark_tag.tag_id IN (1, 2) 
  GROUP BY bookmark.id 
  HAVING count(bookmark.id) = 2) AS anon_1 
WHERE tag.id = bookmark_tag.tag_id 
AND bookmark_tag.bookmark_id = anon_1.id 
AND tag.id NOT IN (1, 2) 
GROUP BY tag.id
```

Comment: This is [Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/). The most common approach seems to be `GROUP BY` and `COUNT`

Comment: My where clause is now "WHERE bookmark_tag.bookmark_model_tag_id IN ($TAG_LIST_ID) GROUP BY bookmark.id HAVING count(*) == $TAG_LIST_SIZE". Is that what you expect ?

Comment: Yes. Assuming that `bookmark_tag` has a unique constraint on it so you can't have duplicates for the same combo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is still an issue but the query should look something like this:

```sql
DECLARE @array TABLE(
    tag varchar(50)
)
INSERT INTO @array
VALUES('test')
INSERT INTO @array
VALUES('braindead')

select * from bookmark_model_bookmark
where id in(
    select bookmark_model_bookmark_id FROM bookmark_tag x INNER JOIN bookmark_model_tag t ON t.id = x.bookmark_model_tag_id
    where t.name in (select tag from @array)
    group by bookmark_model_bookmark_id
    having bookmark_model_bookmark_id >= (select count(0) from @array))
```

In the example above i've used a table but you running any sort of split on a comma delimited string input would end up in a similar position. Let me know if this was what you were looking for or if ive got the wrong end of the stick??? Thanks,

Comment: It's actually a solution. I have updated my question with my current solution.

Comment: well would it be a good idea to close the question. prevent people like myself wasting valuable time?